# Problema al instalar sqliv en kali linux (para deteccion de vulnerabilidades)

Tags: python, linux, pip, kali-linux

Actualmente quiero instalar esta libreria para encontrar vulnerabilidades en aplicaciones webs y de esta forma poder protejer las que ya he creado, el problema es que ya segui varios tutoriales y ninguno me da solucion a su correcta instalacion ya que descargue el el repositorio de github con git clone y despues hice el pip install -r requirements.txt dentro de la carpeta descargadas pero me marca muchos error que no comprendo que serian los siguientes:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-a4ntt7oq/lxml_05cf691aefd241ac8c79286fb90037c2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-a4ntt7oq/lxml_05cf691aefd241ac8c79286fb90037c2/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-vrc61fd1/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.9/lxml                                                                         
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-a4ntt7oq/lxml_05cf691aefd241ac8c79286fb90037c2/                 
    Complete output (568 lines):                                                               
    Building lxml version 4.3.0.                                                               
    Building without Cython.                                                                   
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.34                                                
    running install                                                                            
    running build                                                                              
    running build_py                                                                           
    creating build                                                                             
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9                                                        
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml                                                   
    copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml                                 
    copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml                            
    copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml                      
    copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml                           
    copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml                          
    copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml                             
    copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml                       
    copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml                        
    copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml                      
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes                                          
    copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes          
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/html                                              
    copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/html                      
    copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/html                
    copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/html               
    copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/html                  
    copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/html                 
    copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/html              
    copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/html               
    copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/html                     
    copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/html                
    copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/html                   
    copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/html                      
    copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/html             
    copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/html                  
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron                                     
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron
    copying src/lxml/etree.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml                                
    copying src/lxml/etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml                            
    copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml                           
    copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml                       
    copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes         
    copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes              
    copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes      
    copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes          
    copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes            
    copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes       
    copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes         
    copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes         
    copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes        
    copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes             
    copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes         
    copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes           
    copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes       
    copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes             
    copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes        
    copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes             
    copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes         
    copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/includes       
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources                           
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng                       
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng                                                            
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl                       
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl                                                                
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl                                                                
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1  
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1             
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1                
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1                                                                                              
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1          
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1              
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1                          
    running build_ext                                                                          
    building 'lxml.etree' extension                                                            
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9                                                       
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/src                                                   
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/src/lxml                                              
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/python3.9-RNBry6/python3.9-3.9.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/python3.9-RNBry6/python3.9-3.9.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -Isrc -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/lxml/etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/src/lxml/etree.o -w   
    src/lxml/etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx_modinit_type_init_code’:                              
    src/lxml/etree.c:230559:32: error: ‘PyTypeObject’ {aka ‘struct _typeobject’} has no member named ‘tp_print’                                                                               
    230559 |   __pyx_type_4lxml_5etree_Error.tp_print = 0;                                     
           |                                ^                                                  
        
                                                  ^                     
    Compile failed: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1            
    cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /tmp/xmlXPathInit5gpi5g5o.c -o tmp/xmlXPathInit5gpi5g5o.o                                                                             
    cc tmp/xmlXPathInit5gpi5g5o.o -lxml2 -o a.out                                              
    error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1                     
    ----------------------------------------                                                   
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-a4ntt7oq/lxml_05cf691aefd241ac8c79286fb90037c2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-a4ntt7oq/lxml_05cf691aefd241ac8c79286fb90037c2/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-vrc61fd1/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.9/lxml Check the logs for full command output.
```

Y si ejecuto el siguiente comando python setup.py -i me indica el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pip
ImportError: No module named pip
```

Cabe recalcar que el sistema operativo donde intento instalar esto es en Kali linu suu version mas reciente estable y dentro de una maquina virtual que se creo con virtualbox.

Comment: por favor, coloca el texto en la pregunta, no imágenes.

Comment: @eftshift0 no se como copiar texto de la consola de linux, por eso puse imagenes

Comment: Copias con ctrl-c (si es un terminal en un ambiente grafico) y en stackoverflow colocas 3 acentos circunflejos (comilla sencilla de las que abren citas, o sea, el acento acostado hacia la izquierda) en una línea para abrir, pegas el texto, saltas una línea y colocas otra línea con 3 acentos circunflejos mas y queda formateado.

Comment: @eftshift0 ya se hizo el cambio, gracias

Comment: X lo que se puede ver en el error, en el proceso de instalación se hace la compilación de algo y creo que alguna API de la que depende el código de lo que se está compilando cambió.  PyTypeObject  se define en python así que _creo_ que la versión  de python contra la que estas tratando de **compilar** no es la adecuada: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html

Answer (score 0):

El código de lo que se está tratando de compilar en ese punto está tratando de usar algo que cambió en la API de python. `tp_print` existía hasta python 3.7. A partir de python 3.8 es `tp_vectorcall_offset` (creo). Mirar https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_vectorcall_offset

Lo que estás tratando de compilar es reciente? Porque suena como que el código no lo han ajustado a este cambio (3.8 no es que sea muy viejo, salió en julio de 2019).

Comment: Pues no se que tan reciente sea pero por lo que eh visto su ultimos cambios fueron del año pasado.

Comment: Pues podrías ajustar el código del proyecto que quieres usar (o donde sea que este el fuente que esta roto) o que compiles y uses un python anterior a 3.8